# ¿Porque solo puedo editar una seccion en el archivo de users-dirs.dirs ? LINUX MINT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, server, linux-mint

Tengo un problema

Quiero que todas las subcarpetas de mi usuario redireccionen a un disco externo que esta en la siguiente ruta: "/media/admn/LOT"  (LOT es mi disco externo).

Para lograr mi objetivo  segui las instrucciones de este articulo: https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2019/11/cambiar-la-ubicacion-por-defecto-de-los-directorios-de-usuario-en-gnu-linux/

Edite el archivo : .config/user-dirs.dirs de la siguiente manera:

[image: archivo .dirs]

Al reiniciar me doy cuenta que la unica carpeta que esta enlazada con mi disco externo es la de Desktop.

[image: Modificaciones]

Las demas siguen en el path anterior "home/admn/"
[image: ??]

Me pueden ayudar a solucionar mi problema ? Lo que quiero es que todo las aplicaciones y documentos al **GENERARSE** o **DECARGARSE** se almacenen en un disco duro externo que ya tengo montado en mi servidor linux, muestro archivo de montura:

[image: run-media-admn-LOT.mount]

Gracias.